# How do i get out of Dead Kings?

Tags: assassins-creed-unity

I went to fast Travel back to the Cafe to get my income and i accidently seemed to have been over the fast travel icon for Franciade and it started the Dead Kings DLC. in the memory menu it's Sequence 13 and i'm only in 5 so sorta don't want to play it until i beat the main game, however i can't exit out of the memory as there is no option to quit the memory, just restart it

i have also tried

- quiting out of the game but it reloads back to the start of the memory
- starting a co-op mission and quitting that, but again i end up in Franciade

is there a way for me to quit the Dead Kings DLC? ideally before i get any plot spoilers?